# How can I match this pattern?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have the following text:

```
@keyframes slideRightIn10 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
            transform: translateZ(0);
  }
}
```

With this `"((@)).*\{"` I can match the first line. But how can I match including everything within the outer curly braces. regardless of having newlines (\n) or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some implementations have a global flag `/g`, some allow to match breaks using `[\s\S]`. Since I don't have a vsCode installed I cannot check what's true for it.

The problem is to find the ending `}` since there are some in the example code (and there might even be more in other css-transitions.

You might want to try:

```
@.*?\{[\s\S]+?\n\}
```

The doubled rounded brackets around the `@` make no sense to me. One of those might make sense if you want to have the sing in a group, but I see no case to have it ;)

See https://regexr.com/5duqs

Comment: This works, the only exception is when everything is in one line.

Comment: That's correct, but since you cannot count in regex there is no way to really match this in a oneline-string. If you are **sure to always have exactly 2** keyframe-options, you could `@([\S\s]*?\{){3}([\S\s]*?\}){2}`